# Вертикальное центрирование CSS

Tags: html, css

У меня есть такой код

```
<div class="image" style="color: green;">   
    <div class="text">
       <h1>Heading</h1>
       <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать чтобы контейнер .text был вертикально и горизонтально по центру контейнера .image
Условия: Неизвестна высота контейнера .image, она может быть и 200px, и 1200px, другими словами высота произвольная
Поддержка современными браузерами включая IE 9+
Желательно без использования table
Перерыл весь интернет, нашел много ответов, но никак не смог разобраться как именно это сделать с моим примером, где высота контейнера .image произвольна.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: друг мой - переходи на flexbox и все проблемы решаются двумя строчками css

Comment: Будет полезно https://habr.com/company/netcracker/blog/277433/

Comment: чё минусовать то сразу ?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" style="color: green;">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `flex`:

```css
.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" style="color: green;">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: точно - тремя строчками , а я написал двумя ... ошибся :))